# Tarfile won't open file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tarfile

I have the following code snippet to extract an image from .tzg file:

```
def read_raw_from_tar(tar_fn, fn):
    with tarfile.open(tar_fn) as f:
        m = f.getmember(fn)
        return f.extractfile(m).read()

raw_bytes = read_raw_from_tar("102flowers.tgz", "jpg/image_00001.jpg")
```

When this code is executed in jupyter environment, it returns the following error:

```
~\Anaconda3\envs\AML\lib\tarfile.py in open(cls, name, mode, fileobj, bufsize, **kwargs)
   1576                         fileobj.seek(saved_pos)
   1577                     continue
-> 1578             raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
   1579 
   1580         elif ":" in mode:

ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

Interestingly, the above snippet works when I execute everything in the Coursera's environment.

What can I do to debug this issue?

Comment: Have you tried decompressing the file using the `tar` command?

Comment: You should post the full error trace, along with some other details, like the OS you're using, etc.